# Backup\Restore cmd to Copy db from remote server to desktop

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

Want to backup/restore to copy a dev database from our server to my local machine. Backup is no problem, but restore fails with 'no database specified' error.

Command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Management]
FROM DISK = N'C:\Databases_2021_Jan_14\Databases_2021_Jan_14\management.BAK'
```

Clearly,I've identified the database as Management. Or, that's what I think it's saying. And, I'm doing the restore from a backup file on my C: drive.

Might somebody have some insight on this? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you are executing this command. Is it from SSMS?

Comment: Using LinqPad v.6.11.11. SSMS is so clunky (in my opinion).

Comment: Tried the verify, but it still says no database specified. The BAK file is definitely at the location specified, and I have basically sa rights so I dunno.

Comment: Are you sure this message isn't just LinqPad telling you that you haven't selected a database/connection?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following to verify that the backup is valid and readable first of all.  Then identify if you do have a database named Management in the backup set

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = N'C:\Databases_2021_Jan_14\Databases_2021_Jan_14\management.BAK'

RESTORE HEADERONLY
FROM DISK = N'C:\Databases_2021_Jan_14\Databases_2021_Jan_14\management.BAK'
```